# asp.net mvc clear cookie when clicked browser close button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, browser

ım usinf jquery, ı wanna clear cookie when the user clicked browser's close button.but  beforeunload method is working also for a tags. and the page is changed, beforeunload method working.it must work only for  browser closed clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
       return confirm("You are about to close the window");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First Check that if your web config have the following line or not.If not add those code to your web config to clear cookie in browser close action.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc"></sessionState>
 </system.web>
```

Alternatively 
If you don't set an expiry date it defaults to expire at the end of the session.Please See [jsCookies](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/js/jscookies.html)

Comment: Welcome.Glad to see you are helped.+1